# unix shell - check file exists with YYYY-MM-DD in its name

Tags: shell, unix

I need just to check files exists, but its date in file name

```
test -f /test/import_doku.YYYY-MM-DD.log && echo "OK"
```

Just how to use `date -I` instead of YYYY-MM.DD ? Thanks

Comment: Have you done any research? If not, look up *shell command substitution*

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM.DD`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
test -f /test/import_doku.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log && echo "OK"
```

when the date is current one. If you want to have it for yesterday it become more complicated in UNIX